# Matlab. Create a loop to change variable size with each iteration

Tags: matlab, variables

I am currently trying to run a script that calls a particular function, but want to call the function inside a loop that halfs one of the input variables for roughly 4 iterations.

in the code below the function has been replaced for another for loop and the inputs stated above.

the for loop is running an Euler method on the function, and works fine, its just trying to run it with the repeated smaller step size im having trouble with.

any help is welcomed.

```
f = '3*exp(-x)-0.4*y';
xa = 0;
xb = 3;
ya = 5;
n = 2;

h=(xb-xa)/n;
x = xa:h:xb;
% h = zeros(1,4);
y = zeros(1,length(x));                                      
F = inline(f);
y(1) = ya;

for j = 1:4

    hOld = h;
    hNew = hOld*0.5;
    hOld = subs(y(1),'h',hNew);   

        for i = 1:(length(x)-1)                        

        k1 = F(x(i),y(i));
        y(i+1,j+1) = y(i) + h*k1; 
        end
end

disp(h)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after your comment, something like this

```
for j = 1:4

h=h/2;
x = xa:h:xb;
y = zeros(1,length(x));
y(1) = ya;

    for i = 1:(length(x)-1)                        
       k1 = F(x(i),y(i));
       y(i+1,j+1) = y(i) + h*k1; 
    end
end
```

Comment: the number of iterations are not the problem the loop the half the step size doesnt work, it doesnt update the new variable each time.

Comment: Cheers, simple solutions but had me running around in circles

Comment: happens with everyone :)